# How to display comma separated values inside an input field from the database in php

Tags: php, html

Disclaimer: I am fairly new at this!

This is what I am doing:

```
if ($submit) {
        
    $gasTime= implode(",", $_POST['gasTime']);
    $meterTime= implode(",", $_POST['meterTime']);
    $heatInput= implode(",", $_POST['heatInput']);
    $labTemp= implode(",", $_POST['labTemp']);

    $db->query("INSERT INTO tester SET 
    mainId='$mainId', 
    gasTime='$gasTime', 
    meterTime='$meterTime', 
    heatInput='$heatInput', 
    labTemp='$labTemp'");


    $success = "Tested successfully!";
        
}else{
    

    $db->query("SELECT gasTime FROM tester WHERE gasTime='$gasTime'");


    $gasTime = explode(",", $gasTime );
    $meterTime= explode(",", $meterTime);
    $heatInput= explode(",", $heatInput);
    $labTemp= explode(",", $labTemp);


    **$result = $db->query($sql);
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();**
}
```

HTML :

```
      <tr>
                <td>Time gas</td>
                <td>TG</td>
                <td>s</td>
                   <td><input class="form-control" type="text" id="gasTime" name="gasTime[]" value="<? echo @$row[gasTime ];  ?>"></td>
                   <td><input class="form-control" type="text" id="gasTime" name="gasTime[]" value="<? echo @$row[gasTime ];  ?>"></td>
                   <td><input class="form-control" type="text" id="gasTime" name="gasTime[]" value="<? echo @$row[gasTime ]; ?>"></td>
                   <td><input class="form-control" type="text" id="gasTime" name="gasTime[]" value="<? echo @$row[gasTime ];  ?>"></td>
                   <td><input class="form-control" type="text" id="gasTime" name="gasTime[]" value="<? echo @$row[gasTime ];  ?>"></td>
                <td></td>
     </tr>
```

submitting works perfectly fine but displaying the data to an input field doesn't seem to work.

**EDIT:**
So apparently I wasn't retriving the data and thanks to your help I can now retrieve the values in the input field but the problem now is that I am retriving all 5 values with their commas e.g. "1,2,3,4,5", is there a way to retrieve a value at a time on each input field? e.g. first input 1 second 2 and etc.

Comment: You're running the query but not retrieving the results.

Comment: Hi, I don't understand what you mean but I did test connection and it working fine. They just don't show up in the input field at all I even tried doing this outside the input field and its working fine but when I try to do this on the input field it just doesnt work.
```
 $sql = 'SELECT gasTime FROM tester ';
 $str_arr = explode(",", $gasTime ); 
 $result = $db->query($sql, $str_arr);

 if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   echo "gasTime : " . $row["gasTime "]. "<br>";
  }
 } else {
 echo "0 results";
 }
```

Comment: In the code you posted in your question you have `$db->query("SELECT...")`, but there's no `mysqli_fetch()` or related statement to retrieve the result.

Comment: oh okay I just tried that and its working but the problem is I get all the values with the comma included inside 1 input field. Is there a way to display each comma separated value individually on each input field accordingly ?